# vpn without port forwarding

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm the tech guy in my family and I'm moving out soon, but still want to have remote access to the family network to help them with tech difficulties (ssh into servers, vnc, etc).

The problem is that the router is behind their school's network, so that means no port forwarding (can only port forward as far as the school).

Are there any solutions that provide me with access to the network from anywhere in the world that *don't* involve port forwarding?
I'm pretty adept with computers, but don't have a whole lot of experience with networking.

I'd be remoting in with a windows 10 machine (capable of ssh via bash on windows), and there's an always on linux machine in the house that can be used as some sort of vpn server. (take note: it's VERY old: pentium 3 @1.2 GHZ, 256 MB of ram). If necessary, I could also remote in with a linux machine.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a VPS handy or are you willing to get one? Can you do port forwarding at your new home? // By the way, you should seriously consider getting something like a Raspberry Pi to serve as the VPN anchor. You’ll save *a lot* of power.

Comment: [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: You could use something like TeamViewer which usually allows you to connect to PCs behind routers. I'm not affiliated with them but I am using it to support my family overseas, and also for my own work (to access my work PC from home).

Comment: @DanielB unforunately no VPS and won't be able to get one. And yeah, eventually a raspberry pi would be a good idea. Also won't be able to port forward at the new home :/

Comment: @Darius I've looked briefly into teamviewer cause it advertised vpn capabilities, but never have figured it out. Have you had any luck with it?

Comment: Do you need the VPN capability? I used teamviewer as-is without VPN and it works through my work firewall and my home router without any configuration changes. Simply install it on both client and target, and it works.

Comment: @Darius Yeah, unfortunately the primary use is to be able to ssh into various machines

Comment: Once you are in the target machine (over TeamViewer) it is as if you're sitting on that PC. You can then SSH or do whatever you want from the target PC. But if you prefer to make your machine part of the target network (ie. using VPN) then.. you need a different solution (Daniel B and DavidPostill comments above)

Comment: TeamViewer also offers VPN.

Comment: there's hole-punching: both sides initiate a connection at the same time to the other (public ip) side, with a synchronized, agreed-upon in advance source and destination port: the connection establishes. from this beachhead, you can run other services (tunnels and alike). it depends on *not* having carrier grade NAT (aka symmetric NAT) anywhere. it's also very tricky to put in place (eg: what's my own public ip? how do I send it to the peer while this usually requrires a connection, but that's what I'm trying to do in the first place.. etc.)

Comment: @Darius yeah, teamviewer screen share becomes painfully slow across continents, so I was trying to avoid it. Thanks for the info though! I'll read DavidPostill's link when i have time

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you for the link! It looks like a VPN is the only option available to me, and it also looks like all the VPN services are paid only :/ Is there a free option you know of?

Comment: @DavidPostill ah, nevermind, seems like free options do exist, they just have drawbacks and require some creative googling. Hopefully one of them works and does what i think it will! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DavidPostill darn it, nevermind on the nevermind. All the "free VPNs" i can find are those that unblock your internet by using their own servers

Answer (score -1):

Remote.it provides a good solution with a free tier. Once you install the agent on any compatible device behind the firewall, you use it to open one-off tunnels to any device and port the agent device has access to.